# CSS - Setting an image to a div

Tags: css

I have accordion, and inside that accordion (jqueryui) have a table, that has some values.
Those values will be inserted, and based on those values I will assign a colored box to it. For example lower then 30% its red and above 80% is green. I wanted to make image assigned in classes. So in Javascript I can dynamically insert a class, for example redBox and div gets that image.

For some reason, which I cant figure out... images overlap each other... for example, last div has a red one assigned, and the first one has green. Red is shown instead.

This is the HTML:

```
<div style="height:20px;overflow:visible" id="networkingIndexCollapsible" class="accordionmodsindexing">
         <h3 style="text-align: right"> <span id="scenarioIndex">Some data</span></h3>
            <div>                           

                 <table class="indexingOptions" >
                     <tr>
                                <td>Networking Index:</td>
                                <td><div id="netIndex">Some data<div id="netIndexSquare" class="greenSquare"></div></div></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>- Supplier Index:</td>
                                <td><div id="suppIndex">Some data<div id="supIndexSquare" class="greenSquare"></div></div></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>- Deliver Index:</td>
                                <td><div id="delIndex">Some data<div id="delIndexSquare" class="redSquare"></div></div></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>- Product Index:</td>
                                <td><div id="proIndex">Some data<div id="proIndexSquare" class="redSquare"></div></div></td>
                              </tr>
                        </table>
            </div>
       </div>
 <div> I am just an empty div</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.redSquare
{
display: inline!important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: url(../img/redsquare.png) no-repeat;  
height: 20px;  
padding-left: 55px;
float: right;   
top: 10px;
left: 209px;
position: absolute;
}
.greenSquare
{
display: inline!important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: url(../img/greensquare.png) no-repeat;  
height: 20px; 
padding-left: 55px;
float: right;   
top: 10px;
left: 209px;
position: absolute;
 }
.orangeSquare
  {
display: inline!important;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: url(../img/orangesquare.png) no-repeat;  
height: 20px; 
padding-left: 55px;
float: right;   
top: 10px;
left: 209px;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

Images are 8x8px large.

Image attached shows the problem I am facing.
Green, green, red and read are set in the table, but it shows only the red ones.
I am not that good the CSS, sorry for silly questions. [image]

Removed the position absolute, and the images are shown properly. Now, they are not aligned. How can I align them? Please see the image.
[image]

Comment: Since you're using `position:absolute;`. Could you check if the images are on top of eachother?

Comment: You were correct. I have removed the absolute, and the images are shown properly. Now I have another problem. I cant position the images in line. Please take a look at the image

Comment: What happens if you remove the `float:right;`?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to the colored squares. That way the `top: 10px` will affect them again.